# Render Preview Issue - Looks like UV's are not unwrapped

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, materials, uv, 3d-view

This is the first time I've experienced this and it occurs in both Blender 2.93.8 and 3.0.1. I've created a procedural texture on this building (which is UV unwrapped). It looks correct in the Material Preview, Rendered in Eeevee and also Rendered in Cycles but when I try to view it in the Render Preview, the texture looks like it's applied to an object that is not UV unwrapped.

Eeevee Render
[image]
Cycles Render
[image]
Render Preview
[image]

Comment: Hi :). Looks like displacement only enabled in viewport. Disable displacement and double-check subdiv modifiers ;). That should narrow it down.

Comment: Jachym, I'm not sure where to disable "displacement only" in the viewport. My viewport is set to combined if that's what you mean? I disabled my displacement modifier and I'm not suing any subdiv mods. Same result. This particular material is procedural. I have two materials in other objects, created in Substance Painter and they look fine if that helps narrow down the issue.

Comment: Hi :). Sorry for not being clear. Does your material have a displacement? Does turning it off change things in any way? Because the walls/windows are visibly displaced.

Comment: You can also share parts of your file so others can take a look: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Jachym, the siding has a displacement modifier on it. Turning it off does not change the result. I'm not using a displacement in the material node setup, only a normal map. I'll see if I can simplify my file for upload.

Answer (score 1):

Answer: I had a Boolean object used to trim the wood siding for the roof line. That object's visibility was set to on in the viewport but off in the render. I figured it out while prepping the file for upload, so thank you Jachym.